# What is purpose of using System.img in Android?

Tags: android

What is meant by System.img in Android? What is the purpose of using it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the Android file system, which means all the support files that Android needs, the applications, but also the framework, the Dalvik VM, initialization scripts and so on.

Another part of the file system would be the userdata.img which is mostly empty when you compile the framework.

It is not the OS, that would be either a plain zImage or boot.img (and recovery.img for to boot in recovery mode).

Answer (score 2):

This is the actual system image. It's the OS ... kind of. Look [here](http://source.android.com/porting/bring_up.html) at point four.

**EDIT:** To be more precise the system image along with the kernel image are the forming the OS. The system image alone is one part of the OS.

Comment: Thanks .The point four in that document mean that System.img is the snapshot of OS