# Is there a relation between kernel and system.img

Tags: android, kernel, mobile-development

in other words  if I have android device with `android version 4.0.1`  can I flash it's system.img  to other device have the same android version .if not way

infact I tried but I get black screen

another question 
as we know  inside the **kernel** there are the hardware drivers 
so there is a relation between the kernel and the board.

is there arelation between system.img and the hardware ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is purpose of using System.img in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879717/what-is-purpose-of-using-system-img-in-android)